# Uncountability of a ring defined as a subset of cartesian product

Tags: ring-theory, modules

[image]

For a contradiction, I tried to use the cantor diagonal argument but could not conclude. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The Cantor diagonal argument is exactly what I would do. I can't imagine what would prevent you from concluding that it is uncountable... unless you don't understand Cantor's argument. Can you elaborate on what problem you had, exactly? You should write out how you began the argument, then maybe we can see where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You can embedd the power set of the natural numbers into $\Bbb Z_p$ in the following way. Recall that $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb N) \cong \{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$.

Any sequence $(x_n)_n\in \{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$ defines a unique sequence of natural numbers $(q_n)_n$, where $q_n = \sum \limits_{i=0}^{n-1} x_i p^i$. Obviously $\pi_n(q_{n+1} + p^{n+1}\Bbb Z) = q_n + p^n\Bbb Z$, hence the sequence $(q_n)_n$ is indeed an element of $\Bbb Z_p$. This yields an injective map $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N} \rightarrow \Bbb Z_p$, as different subsets will be distinct in some $n$, so the numbers $q_{n+1}$ will be different.